# GridView Query not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The page opens to a grid that is loaded for the user to edit/Delete the data.The `LoadGrid()` is in a `!IsPostBack`.

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
try
{
    using (var db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        var loadGrid = from t in db.tbl_Providers
                        where t.provider_Deleted == false
                        orderby t.provider_Name.ToLower()
                        select new
                            {
                                t.ProviderId,
                                t.provider_Name,
                            };

        grd_Provider.DataSource = loadGrid;

        grd_Provider.DataBind();
    }
    // Set value of Edit/Delete columns on grid
    // ========================================
    grd_Provider.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Edit/Update";
    grd_Provider.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Delete";

}
catch (SystemException ex)
```

All this code works fine.
What I am trying to do is display the alphabet and the user clicks on the link and it reloads a new query and loads the grid.

The alphabet is working ok as far as I can tell. I have the code load on `Page_Load` and the Void method is further down the page.

```
for (char asciiValue = 'A'; asciiValue <= 'Z'; asciiValue++)
{
LinkButton lnkCharacter = new LinkButton();
lnkCharacter.ID = "lnkCharacter" + asciiValue;
lbl_Alphabet.Controls.Add(lnkCharacter);
lnkCharacter.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(asciiValue);
lnkCharacter.Command += lnkCharacter_Command;

lnkCharacter.Text = Convert.ToString(asciiValue) + " ";
}

void lnkCharacter_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var lbtn = (LinkButton) lbl_Alphabet.FindControl("lnkCharacter" + e.CommandArgument);
        var id = lbtn.Text;

        using (var db = new dbDataContext())
        {
            var query = from n in db.tbl_Providers
                        where n.provider_Name.StartsWith(id) && n.provider_Deleted == false
                        select new
                            {
                               id = n.ProviderId,
                               name = n.provider_Name
                            };

            grd_Provider.DataSource = query;
            grd_Provider.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        var exceptionUtility = new genericExceptions();
        exceptionUtility.genericSystemException(
            ex,
            Server.MachineName,
            Page.TemplateSourceDirectory.Remove(0, 1) +   Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.Remove(0, 1),
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailSupport"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailFrom"],
            string.Empty);
    }
}
```

I have tested the query in LINQPad and it works and returns the results.
When I run it on the page and step through the `Datasource = query` says `expanding the results will enumerate the query`.
I do this ..
`Enumeration yielded no results`
The page reloads and the grid is never show?
Is it something to do with the original grid being loaded on page load and some how conflicting?

I have changed my Alphabet to go in the `IsPostBack` and the page reloads and the alphabet dissapears and the grid is still there loaded as normal. Do I need a different gridview for the Alphabet Query?

Comment: At what time are you setting your data so in which PageEvent?

Comment: What's the value of Id? Shouldn't it be `var id = lbtn.Text`?

Comment: Yes that has sorted that problem as it was set to a LinkButton. Now it is set to the letter I provide. I step through and have added .ToList() and the `count=0` still?

Comment: Can you change the code in your question to match what you have now?  (You indicated that you changed the code.)  One thing that occurs to me is that you set the `Text` value of `lnkCharacter` to be the ASCII value *plus a space character*.  That would look in the debugger like an ordinary character, but if you used that in your LINQ query, it would include the space.  Are you accessing that value in your new code?

Comment: I have added my Edits and tried the query in a different grid and Still Doesnt work Due to the fact It is trying to use the same ish query in both grids. I need a differnt way of achieveing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it looks like to me:

You have this code:

```
lnkCharacter.Text = Convert.ToString(asciiValue) + " ";
```

Then you have this code:

```
var lbtn = (LinkButton) lbl_Alphabet.FindControl("lnkCharacter" + e.CommandArgument);
var id = lbtn.Text;
```

Finally, you have this code:

```
      var query = from n in db.tbl_Providers
                    where n.provider_Name.StartsWith(id) && n.provider_Deleted == false
                    select new
                        {
                           id = n.ProviderId,
                           name = n.provider_Name
                        };
```

By the time you get to the LINQ query, *the value of **id** will have a space at the end*.  So if you hit the "A" link button, you won't be searching for everything that starts with `"A"`, but everything that starts with `"A "`.

You need to either trim `lbtn.Text` when you retrieve it, or use some other method to ensure spaces between your alphabet hyperlinks, like adding `Literal` instances between adding your link buttons.

Comment: You are a star !! Thank You :)